# Order Groups by number of items

Tags: tabulator

I use the tabulator JS library and group my table. How can I order the groups by their number of rows? Eg. the group containing the most items should order at the top.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I do this for sorting dates as the user adds new date-based events. I sort the array after a new event has been added and then use the [replaceData](http://www.tabulator.info/docs/4.3/update) function to update the table. Seems to work pretty well performance-wise.

You would have to work out your own routine logic for sorting based on number of group members.

> The **replaceData** function lets you silently replace all data in the
>   table without updating scroll position, sort or filtering, and without
>   triggering the ajax loading popup. This is great if you have a table
>   you want to periodically update with new/updated information without
>   alerting the user to a change.

---

```
mayData.events = sortEventsByDate(mayData.events);
eventTable.replaceData(mayData.events);
```

---

```
function sortEventsByDate(events) {
    var sorted = events.sort(function (a, b) {
     return new Date(a.startDate).getTime() - new Date(b.startDate).getTime();
    });

    return sorted;
}
```